# Does reviewing flags count towards the Reviewer badge?

Tags: support, review-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

As the title already states - does reviewing flags count towards the Reviewer badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Expanding posts in both the review section and the flag queue counts as a review, and actions taken count as well.

I'm speaking from personal experience, and the fact that both events generate a pretty much identical HTTP request. Note the `review` parameter:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/<post ID>/ajax-load?review=true
```